# $ (1+\sin{x})^{\cos{x}} + (1+\cos{x})^{\sin{x}} > 3x $

Tags: inequality

How do I show that, for $ 0 < x < \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ (first quadrant), the inequality $ (1+\sin{x})^{\cos{x}} + (1+\cos{x})^{\sin{x}} > 3x $ is valid?

I've tried Bernoulli's, but it took me to a false inequality (though all restrictions were respected). I actually thought of using Jensen's, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Bernoulli's inequality would give an upper bound for the LHS, not a lower bound, as the exponent is in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Guess I'm wrong.

PS: Sorry for sudden delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

$$\cos x > 1/\sqrt{2},\quad \sin x > x - x^3/6>0$$
So that we have:
$$(1+\sin{x})^{\cos{x}} + (1+\cos{x})^{\sin{x}} > 
1+\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{x-x^3/6}$$

Now, we can use the series expansion of $(1+a)^x$:
$$(1+a)^x = 1+ \log(1+a)x+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1+a) x^2 + \ldots = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\log^n(1+a) x^n$$
Since all members of the series are positive for $a>0$, we can write:
$$1+\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{x-x^3/6} > 
2+\log(1+1/\sqrt2)x>\frac{x}{2}+2>3x$$
With the last being true since $\pi/4<4/5$, the point where $3x=2+x/2$.

Comment: I could not understand your reasonings. Can you please work with more basic statements/definitions? 

Sorry if I seem rude, but I don't like "taking rabbits of out hats" for math proofs.

Comment: @DelaCorte - is that better?

Comment: Way better. I solved it by another (simpler!) way though, but your solution was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @DelaCorte - welcome to accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sometimes "proofs by Way 1" help me develop "proofs by Way 2", and even "proofs by my own way". Thanks @nbubis.